# Do I need a DNS on a home network?

Tags: nginx, home-url

Having installed a LEMP stack (nginx) on Ubuntu 20.04 I can run a fresh Wordpress site in Firefox using the IP address 127.0.0.1 with no problems. Using 'localhost' doesn't work.

From another Ubuntu 20.04 in my home network I use the IP address 192.168.0.213 and get just a bare-bones view of the Wordpress site. The HTML shows me that all the links in this case contain the hostname 127.0.0.1 like in my first case.

Do I need to have a DNS Server in my simple home network - which I think would be an overkill - or what else can I do ?

Comment: I'm voting to close as this is not really WordPress-specific but more about local server setup. Maybe [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) can help? WP needs a specific URL - be it `foo.test` or `example.com`. It will expect that all requests are possible to parse and access that URL.

Comment: you need a consistent URL that works both locally and on other machines, and WP needs to be configured to use it as its URL. How you do that though isn't a WordPress task, wether you use DNS to do it, or IPs or some other mechanism such as zeroconf/bonjour/avahi or modifying system hosts files etc

Comment: An easier solution to this sort of local development would be to use LOCAL by FlyWheel - it'll even allow you to enable a temporary domain that you can use to access the site from inside and outside your own network. (https://localwp.com)